# Propagating changes to git subtrees using read_tree without network connection

Tags: git, git-subtree

I am using `read-tree` in git to include ProjectA in ProjectB. I have both projects cloned to my computer.

```
/ProjectA

/ProjectB
    /remote/ProjectA
```

When I am making changes to ProjectA from inside ProjectB (`/ProjectB/remote/ProjectA`), currently what I do to propagate all the changes is the following:

1) commit project B (from ProjectB's root directory) :

```
git push origin master
```

2) push ProjectA to its remote repository:

```
git subtree split --prefix=remote/ProjectA --onto temp_branch --branch temp_branch
git push -f https://github.com/myUserName/ProjectA.git temp_branch:master
git branch -D temp_branch;
```

3) update ProjectA (from ProjectA's root directory) :

```
git pull origin master
```

This works fine when I have a network connection.

The thing I love about git is that I can work locally without having to push to my remote repository. When working with `read-tree`s though, I haven't figured out a way to propagate the changes i make inside `ProjectB/remote/ProjectA` to `ProjectA` without doing two pushes and a pull. **How can I keep local repositories that are connected by the `read-tree` feature synchronized, without having to have a network connection?** What I am hoping go make work somehow is by committing ProjectA from inside ProjectB, the changes would get committed to all projects that use ProjectA, and to ProjectA itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just pull from your local path instead of pushing and pulling from the remote.

Git doesn't care.

```
cd /ProjectA
git pull ../ProjectB/remote/ProjectA temp_branch
```